# Use R user defined function in C

Tags: c, r, function, interface, call

I am trying to extend an R package which is totally written in C. I have the following issue: in the C code I want to make a call to an R user defined function as optim routine does. Nevertheless, when I try to trace down the main steps in optim, I am (more or less) able to follow the steps in the C source code, but as soon as I try to understand how optim is called from R (via .External2) I cannot even figure out what is the link between the arguments passed through .External2 to optim. Specificaly, in `src/library/stats/src/optim.c` we have the following

```
SEXP optim(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP rho)
```

and in `src/library/stats/R/optim.R` we have that (what I suppose to be) optim is called in this way

```
.External2(C_optim, par, fn1, gr1, method, con, lower, upper)
```

How arguments call, op, args and rho are passed to optim by .External2?

Some years ago I read about a function R_call or something like this to call R functions into C. I remember that even at that time this function was deprecated, but it is just to make clear what I need.

Comment: IANACP, but it looks like the arguments are bundled up into a list by `.External2`'s `...` formal, and then unpacked in the C code for `optim` by [the series of statements](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/optim.c#L192) of the form `args = CDR(args); fn = CAR(args);`, `args = CDR(args); gr = CAR(args);`, `args = CDR(args); method = CAR(args);`,  etc. (If you're not familiar with `CAR` and `CDR`, [see here, for example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR).)

Comment: Although I am not an R guru, I do not see how arguments are bundled into a list by `.External2` because, for instance, none of the arguments in .External is an environment (which is required by `optim`, e.g. `SECP rho`). Thanks for the reply anyway!

Comment: Not exactly a solution to your problem, but do check out SWIG--it'll make your life a lot eaiser: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/R.html

Comment: Oh thanks, I did not not about SWIG and it seems useful. I will give it a try.I have solved my problem by evaluating an R expression into C as in Writing R Extesions (Section 5.11). The solution (IMHO) is not as elegant as `optim`, `optimize`, `uniroot`, etc function do in R, but it works. Nevertheless, if some R guru wants to explain how `optim` works, I would be very happy!